# Error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

How can I solve this error?

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

My SQL code :

```
SELECT 
   RTRIM(invoiceNo) as [Order No.],
   RTRIM(InvoiceDate) as [Order Date],
   RTRIM(SubTotal) as [SubTotal],
   RTRIM(VATPer) as [Vat+ST %],
   RTRIM(VATAmount) as [VAT+ST Amount],
   RTRIM(DiscountPer) as [Discount %],
   RTRIM(DiscountAmount) as [Discount Amount],
   RTRIM(GrandTotal) as [Grand Total],
   RTRIM(TotalPayment) as [Total Payment],
   RTRIM(PaymentDue) as [Payment Due] 
FROM  
   Invoice_Info 
WHERE 
   InvoiceDate BETWEEN @d1 AND @d2 
ORDER BY  
   InvoiceDate desc
```

And I call this using a `SqlCommand` from C#, adding these parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30, "InvoiceDate").Value = dtpInvoiceDateFrom.Value.Date;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30, "InvoiceDate").Value = dtpInvoiceDateTo.Value.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must remove the ".Date" from the values, because DateTimePicker.Value.Date is returning only the date part of the field.

Also you can change the parameters to the following:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpInvoiceDateFrom.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtpInvoiceDateTo.Value;
```

Comment: i use your following code but it doesnt work and appear with error again

Comment: If the InvoiceDate is really datetime column, then can you erase the RTRIM from it in the Select statement. RTRIM is only for string values if I am not mistaken. And try again the sql statement.

Comment: Another option to test your sql query is to take the values from dtpInvoiceDateFrom.Value and add them as values in the query in SQL Management Studio. This will allow you to see if there is a problem in the query or in the parameters.